# When should one stop playing this game?

Tags: probability, gambling

> You play a game using a standard six-sided die. You start with 0 points. Before every roll, you decide whether you want to continue the game or end it and keep your points. After each roll, if you rolled 6, then you lose everything and the game ends. Otherwise, add the score from the die to your total points and continue/stop the game.
>   When should one stop playing this game?

Let $X$ represents the number that comes up on the die.

Therefore the game continues until $X<6$,

So, $P(X=6)=nCr  p^r q^{n-r}$ where $r=1$

$$ \dfrac{1}{6}=nC_1 \times \dfrac{1}{6} \times \biggr (\dfrac{5}{6}\biggr )^{n-1}$$

$$1=n \times \biggr(\dfrac{5}{6}\biggr)^{n-1}$$

$$\boxed {n = 1}$$

Am I wrong?

Comment: The game continues “as long as” $X<6$ is a better syntax

Comment: You could also consider looking at the probability distribution of the random sum for some overkill.

Comment: However, does my answer seem correct?

Comment: "$X$ represents the number that comes up on the die" But there might be several throws with a die, leading to several numbers. Should it not be a sequence $X_1,X_2,\dots$?

Comment: @drhab I'd be grateful if my solution seems correct.

Comment: Sorry but it does not.

Comment: @drhab There's no way...

Comment: What is $n$? ...

Comment: @Bram28 $n = 2$

Comment: Or maybe I should have mentioned that one want to maxime the total score. Is that the problem?

Comment: @Busi I was not asking for the value of $n$ (which, by the way, you claim has to be $1$ later in your post), but rather what it *means* ... is it the number of times you have thrown the die? Or ...?

Comment: @Bram28 Which does seem more natural? I think it is the number of the times I've thrown. Let's analyze it on both condition. Or maybe this problem is about maximize value.

Comment: @Busi Well, *you* are the one that introduced $n$ ... so *you* should know what you meant by $n$ by using $n$ ...   and what do you mean  y 'both conditions ... given that you only give one?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you gained $n$ points.

If you decide to go on that situation then the expectation is $$\frac16(n+1)+\cdots+\frac16(n+5)+\frac16\cdot0=\frac56n+\frac52$$

So you could decide to stop if $\frac56n+\frac52<n$ or equivalently $n>15$.

Comment: Does my answer seem correct?

Comment: I cannot discern what you are trying to answer. Is it your conclusion that one should stop after playing exactly $n=1$ game?

Comment: maybe it is. However, I found the answer as $n = 1$. Otherwise, you can comment on the way I found the answer.